# Q-Learning without a reward grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reinforcement-learning

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to implement Q-learning in C#(Unity specifically). I have a car which needs to drive along a grid path, like shown:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1JLU.png) - Where Green is goal(+reward), gray and off-grid are obstacles(-reward) and blue is the car. I've been looking at a few examples/guides on how to implement this (pseudo-code mostly), but they seem to know a pre-defined grid to work(A reward grid), which I'm unsure how to implement in my scenario.

The idea is that my car have three states & actions:

- States: Driving in left lane, driving in center lane, driving in right lane
- Actions: Move one up and left, move one up and right, move one up

I'm trying to follow this: http://mnemstudio.org/path-finding-q-learning-tutorial.htm and adapt that into my system - but I fail to see how to do the adaption. Wouldn't this require my Q-matrix to be much`much larger, as each cell would be an individual state? Lets say my track is 16 cells long, with 3 lanes, would this mean I should have a 48 states * 3 actions grid?

Edit: To simplify my post, I thin what I'm struggling with is how to connect my environment and my Q-matrix, so I can modify my q-matrix values depending on the behaviour of my agent in my kind of system.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in grid-based environments like your car example, each cell corresponds with a different state. So, your environment may have the 3 actions you described (move one up and left, move one up and right, move one up), but definitively doesn't have three states.

As you point in the last part of the question, if your track is 16 cells long and 3 lanes, your environment should be modelled with `16 * 3 = 48` states. Therefore, your Q-matrix size should be 48 x 3.

With this setup, you can easily map your agent state (car position in the track) with the Q-matrix.